# Getting the length of a list

Tags: r, arraylist

I am attempting to decipher a list `res` which has structure as per below:

[image]

How would I go about converting this to a 21 (row) by 2 (column) dataframe?

I can do it by manually hard-coding the 21:

```
data.frame(matrix(unlist(res), nrow=21 ))
```

However I would like to use `length(res)` which unfortunately returns `1`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is a list use `[[` to index it to get the matrix and then convert to dataframe.

```
data.frame(res[[1]])
```

Or use `unlist` with `recursive = FALSE`

```
data.frame(unlist(res[[1]], recursive = FALSE))
```

---

Using a reproducble example,

```
res <- list(matrix(letters,ncol = 2))
data.frame(res[[1]])

#   X1 X2
#1   a  n
#2   b  o
#3   c  p
#4   d  q
#5   e  r
#6   f  s
#7   g  t
#8   h  u
#9   i  v
#10  j  w
#11  k  x
#12  l  y
#13  m  z
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also `magrittr::extract2`

```r
res %>% magrittr::extract2(1)
## A tibble: 21 x 2
#   V1    V2
#   <chr> <chr>
# 1 O     M
# 2 W     S
# 3 C     Q
# 4 L     C
# 5 M     K
# 6 R     M
# 7 U     Q
# 8 I     T
# 9 K     J
#10 H     V
## … with 11 more rows
```

or use `purrr::flatten_dfc`

```r
purrr::flatten_dfc(res)
## A tibble: 21 x 2
#   V1    V2
#   <chr> <chr>
# 1 O     M
# 2 W     S
# 3 C     Q
# 4 L     C
# 5 M     K
# 6 R     M
# 7 U     Q
# 8 I     T
# 9 K     J
#10 H     V
## … with 11 more rows
```

### Sample data

```r
set.seed(2018)
res <- list(
    as_tibble(matrix(sample(LETTERS, 21 * 2, replace = T), nrow = 21, ncol = 2))
)
```